# How do I add an input form when clicking an HTML link using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a `div` containing a link. When clicked, the link should be replaced by `<input type="text">`, but it just doesn't work.

Any other html code works, but for some reason I can not replace the link with an input:

```js
function working() {
  document.getElementById("working").innerHTML = "<h1>Test</h1>";
};
function notworking() {
  document.getElementById("notworking").innerHTML = "<input type="text">";
};
```

```html
<div id="working">
  <a onclick="working();" href="#">This works!</a>
</div>
<div id="notworking">
  <a onclick="notworking();" href="#">This doesn't!</a>
</div>
<p>
Notice that the entire code doesn't work unless you comment out the "notworking()" function!
</p>
```

Comment: Please include all code in the question

Comment: You have a typo resulting in a syntax error.  When something "isn't working" you should *at least* look at the debugging console for any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need single quotes for your nested quotes;

```
function notworking() {
document.getElementById("notworking").innerHTML = "<input type='text'>";
}
```

I've done this so many times haha, when using quotes inside double quotes always use single quotes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh man haha thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line:

```
document.getElementById("notworking").innerHTML = "<input type="text">";
```

You're starting the string with double quotes but using double quotes within the string. This causes a syntax error in your JavaScript. If you need double quotes inside the string, use single quotes around the whole string, and vice versa.

change

`document.getElementById("notworking").innerHTML = "<input type="text">";`

to

`document.getElementById("notworking").innerHTML = '<input type="text">';`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. Notice the quotes around `text`

```
document.getElementById("notworking").innerHTML = "<input type='text'>";
```